# using mocha test with node. this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'files' of undefined

Tags: mocha.js

**i am making mocha test cases. but when i am running my file giving error. this my error.** 
**TypeError: Cannot set property 'files' of undefined**

this is my code

```
const describe = require('mocha');
const assert = require('assert');

    describe('Array', () => {
      describe('#indexOf()', () => {
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', () => {
          // assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
          assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
        });
      });
    });
```

this is error

```
E:\Node\Angular-node-mysql\server\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:85
  this.files = [];
             ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'files' of undefined
    at Mocha (E:\Node\Angular-node-mysql\server\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:85:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node\Angular-node-mysql\server\routes\userRoute\user.spec.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: Sadly I do not have an answer. I am running into the very same issue, and then only after ``npm linking gulp``. My *js* testing bits are kind of happily accidentally somewhat aligned at the moment with this being the obstacle. Trying to connect the bits using VS2017 *nodejs* blank project as the basis, *mocha* for testing, *gulp* for tasking, etc.

Answer (score 5):

you should use require mocha first then define describe from mocha

```
let mocha = require('mocha');
let describe = mocha.describe;
```

as Gribbs comment here
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2314#issuecomment-387944573